# How to Retain Columns of lists in a dataframe with a specific value?

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I have a dataframe as shown

```
id     A      B
1      2     ['a', 'c', 'd']
3      4     ['s', 'z', 'a', 'e']
5      6     ['b', 'z', 'd']
7      8     ['a', 'g']
```

Now, I would like to extract all rows that have 'a' in column "B" 
Desired Output:

```
id     A      B
1      2     ['a', 'c', 'd']
3      4     ['s', 'z', 'a', 'e']
7      8     ['a', 'g']
```

Help regarding accomplishing the above in python using Pandas will be appreciated :)

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Just FYI apply is time cost function, carefully use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
new_df=df[df['B'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
print(new_df)

   id  A             B
0   1  2     [a, c, d]
1   3  4  [s, z, a, e]
3   7  8        [a, g]
```

---

**Detail:**

```
df['B'].apply(lambda x: 'a'  in x)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

---

Also you can use [`callable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable):

```
df.loc[lambda x: x.B.str.join(',').str.contains('a')]
```

---

**Time Measure for 400 rows**

```
%%timeit
df[pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist()).eq('a').any(1).values]
3.72 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
df.loc[lambda x: x.B.str.join(',').str.contains('a')]
1.33 ms ± 90.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
df[df['B'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
786 µs ± 9.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Do not use apply for this case for loop even better

Comment: FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: thanks for the info . I already proposed an alternative solution

Comment: You can test the timing , i think str.join will little better

Comment: As you can see both methods are similar. Instead yours is significantly worse. But obviously this might not be repetitive @WeNYoBen.

Comment: What sample size you are using ?

Comment: 400 rows, e same columns thah OP

Comment: for 40000 rows apply method  is 
three times faster but callable (with str.contains an join) is similar your solution

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df[pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist()).eq('a').any(1).values]
```

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions.

Comment: @Andreas I think the answer is good enough to explain itself , since no logic here

Comment: The answer is good enough, but the question lacks the code attempts from OP. Hence, there is no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Andreas aha, I got u. The question quality is a problem for New user.

Comment: Yes, hence it's recommended to guide them to improve the question before providing answer to them

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "A", "B"])

i=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if "a" in row['B']:
        new_df.loc[i] = row
        i+=1
```